# How to read emails on Global Address List of Exchange Server 2010?

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

How to read all the emails of global address list of an Exchange Server 2010 using EWS Managed API? I could not find any methods in the API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In Exchange 2010 there are no direct methods to do this (there is in 2013) so you need to use a workaround. If you have less the 100 entries in the GAL you can just use the ResolveName operation and try resolving "SMTP:" which will return the top 100 entries. Another option is put all the emailaddresses you want to resolve in a Group and then use ExpandGroup http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh532557%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx . Otherwise just use LDAP http://www.infinitec.de/post/2011/10/25/Searching-the-Global-Address-List-C-Edition.aspx

Cheers
Glen